# ignoring #pragma comment ws2_32.lib [-Wunknown-pragmas]

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to compile some C++ code using Qt creator that has to connect to a socket for sending and receiving data. I have linked the library file, added the flag `win32: LIBS+= -lWS2_32`. Attaching the code snippet below:

```cpp
...
#include<winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")
#include<windows.h>
...
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s;
uint8_t* encode_buffer;
uint8_t* decode_buffer;
uint16_t encode_buffer_length;
uint16_t decode_buffer_length;
if (send(s, encode_buffer, encode_buffer_length,0)<0){
    ...
}
if((recv_size=recv(s, decode_buffer, decode_buffer_length,0))== SOCKET_ERROR){
    ...
}
```

And my following issues are:

```
Warning: ignoring #pragma comment [-Wunknown-pragma]
Error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*} to 'const char*'[-fpermissive]
Error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*} to 'char*'[-fpermissive]
Error: no matching function for call to 'send'
Error: no matching function for call to 'recv'
Warning: unknown pragma ignored
```

I have added the `ws2_32.lib` file to the project as an external library, and mentioned it in the `#pragma` directive.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: `#pragma comment` is a Visual C++ (MSVC) specific pragma. Qt Creator probably uses GCC, where that pragma doesn't exist. You should also change the order of your `#include` directives, you should `#include <windows.h>` first.

Comment: The rest looks like you want the program to interpret he `uinti8_t*` as a `char*`, so probably a good place to employ a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Side note: I don't think the build got to the linker yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude actually, the include order is fine. `windows.h` includes `winsock.h` by default, which is not compatible with `winsock2.h`. By including `winsock2.h` first, it disables `winsock.h` and all is good. But if `winsock.h` is included first, all hell breaks out in `winsock2.h` (lots of "multiple declaration" errors, etc)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also, `#pragma comment(...)` is not specific to just VC++, Borland/Embarcadero compilers also support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the *warnings* (not errors), the `#pragma` you are using is not supported by most compilers (Microsoft and Embarcadero compilers do). So just remove it altogether (you already link to the library in the project makefile), or at least disable it with an appropriate `#if/def`.

As for the rest of the *errors*, `send()` and `recv()`expect `char*` pointers, not `uint8*` pointers. A simple type-cast will suffice.

Try this:

```
...
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")
#endif
...
if (send(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(encode buffer), encode_buffer_length, 0) < 0) {
    ...
}
if ((recv_size = recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(decode buffer), decode_buffer_length, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    ...
}
...
```